# How to shuffle an array the same way every time?

Tags: arrays, ruby, shuffle

Calling `Array#shuffle` shuffles an array randomly, but I want to shuffle reproducibly – *i.e.*, the same way every time. Is there a method for that? I want to call, for example, `shuffle_with_key(123)` and get the same result every time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Array#shuffle` can take a seeded `Random` instance.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
seed = 1

a.shuffle(random: Random.new(seed))
# => [4, 1, 3, 2]

a.shuffle(random: Random.new(seed))
# => [4, 1, 3, 2]
```

Just replace `seed = 1` with whatever random seed you want to use.

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is. Look the below :

```
(arup~>~)$ pry --simple-prompt
>> a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
=> [1, 2, 3]
>> a.shuffle(random: Random.new(1))
=> [1, 3, 2]
>> a.shuffle(random: Random.new(1))
=> [1, 3, 2]
>> a.shuffle(random: Random.new(1))
=> [1, 3, 2]
>> a.shuffle(random: Random.new(1))
=> [1, 3, 2]
>> a.shuffle(random: Random.new(1))
=> [1, 3, 2]
>> a.shuffle(random: Random.new(2))
=> [3, 2, 1]
>> a.shuffle(random: Random.new(2))
=> [3, 2, 1]
>> a.shuffle(random: Random.new(2))
=> [3, 2, 1]
```

Read the documentation of [`shuffle(random: rng) → new_ary`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-shuffle)

> The optional rng argument will be used as the random number generator.

You method would look like :-

```
def shuffle_with_key(ary,rng)
  ary.shuffle(random: Random.new(rng))
end
```